# What is the purpose of the declaration "template auto A::f(int t) -> decltype(t + g())"

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[expr.prim.this](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#this-2):

> If a declaration declares a member function or member function
>   template of a class X, the expression this is a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to cv-qualifier-seq X” between the optional cv-qualifier-seq
>   and the end of the function-definition, member-declarator, or
>   declarator. It shall not appear before the optional cv-qualifier-seq
>   and it shall not appear within the declaration of a static member
>   function (although its type and value category are defined within a
>   static member function as they are within a non-static member
>   function). [ Note: This is because declaration matching does not occur
>   until the complete declarator is known. — end note ] [ Note: In a
>   trailing-return-type, the class being defined is not required to be
>   complete for purposes of class member access. Class members declared
>   later are not visible.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   char g();
>   template<class T> auto f(T t) -> decltype(t + g())
>     { return t + g(); }
> };
> template auto A::f(int t) -> decltype(t + g());
> ```

I don't know much about templates, but in the example that follows I didn't have to use this declaration to instantiate the member template function `A::f`

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct A {
    char g();
    template<class T> auto f(T t) -> decltype(t + g())
    { return t + g(); }
};

char A::g() { return 'a'; }

struct C {
    operator float() { return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << a.f(1) << '\n';
    std::cout << a.f(1.0) << '\n';
    std::cout << a.f(C{}) << '\n';
}
```

which prints

```
98
98.00
98.00
```

Comment: The standard is not a style guide. In this case it provides examples. The last line of code in the example shows how you can declare a specialization for that template if you need one (note that that line declares `A::f(int)`). It does not imply that you **have to** declare any specializations. So, yes, your code is just fine if you don't need to specialize `A::f(int)`.

Comment: Could you tell me which grammar production in the spec gives support to this declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's purpose is to illustrate that you can use `this` (which is implicit when the member function `g` is named) in the trailing-return-type of a member function or member function template, even when the member is redeclared outside of the class :)

As to the name of this construct, it is an [explicit instantiation definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Explicit_instantiation), specified in the [[temp.explicit]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit) section of the standard.